# exposing c++ class to python

Tags: python, c++

Forgive me, I'm an engineer tasked with programming.  I'm not a programmer.  I am somewhat familiar with python.  My goal is to get this radio working using a raspberry pi 3, but all of the radio's code is written in c++.  I need to expose these c++ classes to python, and I'm making progress but I'm stuck.
In this class, There is a function to turn the radio on (SX1272::ON()) and in this function, it calls the setMaxCurrent function...

```
uint8_t SX1272::ON()
{
     uint8_t state = 2;

     #if (SX1272_debug_mode > 1)
         printf("\n");
         printf("Starting 'ON'\n");
     #endif

    setMaxCurrent(0x1B);

int8_t SX1272::setMaxCurrent(uint8_t rate)
{
    int8_t state = 2;
    byte st0;

    #if (SX1272_debug_mode > 1)
        printf("\n");
        printf("Starting 'setMaxCurrent'\n");
    #endif
```

....

I have started wrapping this class in python, but after compiling, I get a segmentation fault with the following...

```
PyObject* ON(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    PyObject* SX1272Capsule = NULL;

    SX1272* sx1272 = (SX1272*)PyCapsule_GetPointer(SX1272Capsule, "SX1272Ptr");
    sx1272->ON();
    return Py_BuildValue("i", 0);
}

PyObject* setMaxCurrent(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    PyObject* SX1272Capsule = NULL;
    uint8_t rate;

    PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "b", &SX1272Capsule, &rate);

    SX1272* sx1272 = (SX1272*)PyCapsule_GetPointer(SX1272Capsule, "SX1272Ptr");
    sx1272->setMaxCurrent(rate);
    return Py_BuildValue("");
}
```

something is wrong with the setMaxCurrent part. not sure what??? I hope this makes sense and I hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Please change your title to something more clear? It is very confusing if you were just browsing on StackoverFlow finding questions to answer and suddenly you see `exposing c++ class to python`...

Comment: Use a debugger to see exactly where it breaks, how it got to that point, step through your code and watch it do what it does. If I had to guess, my guess would be that the problem is probably caused by your pointers not actually pointing to what your code assumes they point to…

Comment: I agree that its in the pointers.  Just not sure how to fix it. I also agree that the title could be more clear.  I'll likely post a simplified example tomorrow to illustrate my problem better.  I can't find a way to step through the code because I have to run the code with sudo...  otherwise I get a permission error. That makes it tough to use something like Thonny to step through.

Comment: I think it is with your `PyObject SX1272Capsule = NULL;` https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/capsule.html#c.PyCapsule_New. Create a new object.

Comment: I'll add that creating a native module with the CPython API is probably the most manual, painstaking way of interfacing C++ and Python. On the pi, I've had luck wrapping a C++ class in C functions, and calling them from Python with [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#main-mode-of-usage). [PyBind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/classes.html) seems to be another popular method of simplifying module developement, but I haven't used it.